# Реализация widget как у Google Calendar

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Собираюсь сделать widget, похожие на Рис.2. Получается только с одним ListView, с двумя ListView и более нельзя сделать, как на картинках ниже. Пожалуйста, посоветуйте мне, как можно это реализовать, или, может, есть `open source`.

[image: рисунок 1] [image: рисунок 2]

Comment: А где тут несколько листов?

Comment: @Чад, Я сомневаюсь, что тут несколько ListView, но я не знаю, как сделать View элементы, как Today, tomorrow. Чтобы разделить визуально на дни недели.

Comment: Это Вам в адаптере листа надо выдавать разные view для элементов. Почитайте просто про листы и адаптеры. В гугле полно информации.

Comment: @Чад, частично вы правы, но видимо не работали с Виджетами, там нет адаптеров, которые наследуют ArrayAdapter. Но проблему решил именно так, как вы сказали.

Comment: :-) Там это сервисы :-) И Фабрики. Принцип тот же, объвязка чуть подленнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему подстановкой разных layout в RemoteViews:

```
public class ScheduleViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews row = null;
        if (position % 2 == 1)
            row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);
        else
            row = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(), R.layout.row_red);

        ...........

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2; //По умолчанию ставят 1, но 
                 //тогда не будет показываться R.layout.row_red
    }
}
```